# Spawn only one gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am creating a 2d space shooter game. My issue is that I want when the number will be as set, there will spawn only one power up, but not continuesly. I tried a lot of methods but still it is spawning continuesly. Don't pay attention to other code, everything works just the part were is spawning continuesly no, need just one spawn.

```
void Update () 
{
    Debug.Log (curast);
    if (curast == 3.333334f) 
    {
        while(SpawnMB == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= spawnbl; i++) {
                SpawnMB = true;
                Vector2 pos = new Vector2 (Random.Range (x5, x6), Random.Range (y5, y6));
                Instantiate (MB, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                SpawnMB = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

spawnbl is equal to 1. Please help.

Comment: Well every time `Update` is called, it sets the `SpawnMB` flag to true, so it will always run the `while` loop.

Comment: I know I have tried with brake but no working

Comment: do you have an idea how I can fix that

Comment: Don't set it to true inside there! Maybe set it on at the start of your app.

Comment: ok  will try to make it as default true not false;

Comment: So what I did was delet the true from update and added to the default, not working at all

Comment: wait iset it in start

Comment: and now I don't know why there are spawning 2 powers, why not one?

Comment: I deleted from update = true and I set t in start = true but now there are spawning 2 not one

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just fiex the problem thatnks to your help, I have delted the I <= spawnbl and added I < spawnbl, thanks for your help work perfectly!